# How to split dataframe made from a json/dict entries into multiple columns for traversal?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have data that I have pulled from GitHub API for a research project I am involved in. The goal is to pull the issues from a repo so we can streamline our efforts to categorize issues by their # of comments, date of creation, etc. So the idea would be to have a csv or json created that has each issue # and it's respective attributes as one column.

The problem I'm running into is that each issue is separated into rows, but all the information is in one column rather than multiple. Here is a sample of the code:

```
def run_query(repo_name, repo_owner, sample_amount = 50, state = "CLOSED"):
    request = requests.post('https://api.github.com/graphql', json={'query': gen_query(repo_name, repo_owner, sample_amount, state)}, headers=headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        return request.json()
    else:
        raise Exception("Query failed to run by returning code of {}. {}".format(request.status_code, gen_query(repo_name, repo_owner)))

def gen_query(repo_name, repo_owner, sample_amount = 50, state = "CLOSED"):
    query = """
    query {{
        repository(owner: "{}", name: "{}") {{
            issues(last:{}, states:{}) {{
              edges {{
                node {{
                  number
                  url
                  title
                  createdAt
                  comments {{
                    totalCount
                  }}
                  labels(first: 10) {{
                    edges {{
                      node {{
                        name
                      }}
                    }}
                  }}
                }}
              }}
            }}
        }}
    }}""".format(repo_owner, repo_name, sample_amount, state)
    return query

query_res = run_query("yolov5", "ultralytics", sample_amount=3)
query_proc = query_res['data']['repository']['issues']['edges']
```

which returns this:

```
[{'node': {'comments': {'totalCount': 1},
           'createdAt': '2021-06-16T05:00:55Z',
           'labels': {'edges': [{'node': {'name': 'question'}}]},
           'number': 3628,
           'title': 'Image resize function in detect.py',
           'url': 'https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/3628'}},
 {'node': {'comments': {'totalCount': 4},
           'createdAt': '2021-06-16T10:22:08Z',
           'labels': {'edges': [{'node': {'name': 'question'}}]},
           'number': 3636,
           'title': "What's the difference between 'ema' and 'model' in "
                    'checkpoints',
           'url': 'https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/3636'}},
 {'node': {'comments': {'totalCount': 2},
           'createdAt': '2021-06-16T14:52:02Z',
           'labels': {'edges': [{'node': {'name': 'TODO'}},
                                {'node': {'name': 'bug'}}]},
           'number': 3644,
           'title': 'Training crash on first validation: Error in processing '
                    'validate dataset path',
           'url': 'https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/3644'}}]
```

[Img of DataFrame of the Dict to show issue better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoKov.png)

So it's separated the issues into entries but the actual data from each issue is just one giant text, rather than individual attributes. Ideally I would want it to resemble this dict:

```
dictionary = {0 : {'number': 3628, 'url': 'https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/3628', 'title': 'Image resize function in detect.py', 'labels': 'question', 'created at': '2021-06-16T05:00:55Z', 'comments': 1},
              1 : {'number': 3636, 'url': 'https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/3636', 'title': "What's the difference between 'ema' and 'model' in checkpoints", 'labels': 'question', 'created at': '2021-06-16T10:22:08Z', 'comments': 4},
              2 : {'number': 3644, 'url': 'https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/3644', 'title': "Training crash on first validation: Error in processing validate dataset path", 'labels': "TODO, question", 'created at': '2021-06-16T14:52:02Z', 'comments': 2}}
```

[Ideal/Properly Formatted DataFrame Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wybNu.png)

If you want to look further into it, [here is the gist just incase](https://gist.github.com/JacobSPalmer/2a61b6e9fab3fa432630dd4c6e14816b)! Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You may iterate on each row to apply your desired output

- take all values from `node` key
- overwrite `comments` with the `totalCount`
- overwrite `labels` with inner values from `labels.edges`

```
v = [{'node': {'comments': {'totalCount': 1}, 'createdAt': '2021-06-16T05:00:55Z',
               'labels': {'edges': [{'node': {'name': 'question'}}]},
               'number': 3628, 'title': 'Image....py', 'url': 'https://.../3628'}},
     {'node': {'comments': {'totalCount': 4}, 'createdAt': '2021-06-16T10:22:08Z',
               'labels': {'edges': [{'node': {'name': 'question'}}]},
               'number': 3636, 'title': "What's ...checkpoints", 'url': 'https://.../3636'}},
     {'node': {'comments': {'totalCount': 2}, 'createdAt': '2021-06-16T14:52:02Z',
               'labels': {'edges': [{'node': {'name': 'TODO'}},
                                    {'node': {'name': 'bug'}}]},
               'number': 3644, 'title': 'Training ... path', 'url': 'https://.../3644'}}]
result = [
    {
        **value['node'],
        'comments': value['node']['comments']['totalCount'],
        'labels': ", ".join(x['node']['name'] for x in value['node']['labels']['edges'])
    }
    for value in v
]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df)
print(df.to_markdown())
```

|  | comments | createdAt | labels | number | title | url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2021-06-16T05:00:55Z | question | 3628 | Image....py | https://.../3628 |
| 1 | 4 | 2021-06-16T10:22:08Z | question | 3636 | What's ...checkpoints | https://.../3636 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-06-16T14:52:02Z | TODO, bug | 3644 | Training ... path | https://.../3644 |

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df1 = df['node'].apply(pd.Series)
df1['comments'] = df1['comments'].str['totalCount']
df1['labels'].str['edges'].explode().str['node'].str['name'].fillna(
    '').groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for this solution, this seems to work with this test case. However, not all issues have a label so instead of looking like this:

'labels': {'edges': [{'node': {'name': 'question'}}]}

It looks like this: {'edges': []} and then gives me this error - TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found. I believe that is because since it has nothing, it cannot be modified like a string. Any quick fixes for that?

Comment: @JacobPalmer That's because it contains `NAN` you need to fill `NaN` values before applying any agg function. Updated my answer!!